# getting a full line from unique first two columns

Tags: unique

I have two files, and need to find the line given from a unique set of the first two columns.

Essentially, I have
    File 1:

```
11    23     0.98  0.43
13    15     0.87  0.23
14    18     0.96  0.43
23    42     0.55  0.64
```

and
    File 2:

```
11    14     0.64  0.47
11    23     0.77  0.34
13    15     0.87  0.23
42    23     0.65  0.55
```

and need an output of

```
11   14      0.64  0.47
```

Most things I've seen require some form of reordering of the first two columns, which needs to be avoided. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So, you want to print lines from file 2 only if the key exists in both files and the values are not identical?

Comment: Apologies, had a moment of number dyslexia. The edited version here is better. I'm trying to get the entire line of file 2 if the first two columns in that line are unique from File 1. It is possible that columns 3 and 4 can have the same value between files, otherwise this would be much simpler. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for this, here is some pseudo-code:

```
for every item x in the first column
  for every item y in the second column
     if x is equal to y then
         //do your stuff here
```

Comment: I thought about that, but you can have repeating numbers in the columns, and have found that this causes a miscount in the number of lines/ doesn't really do what I need it to. Also, these files can be rather enormous, which means the loops can take some time to power through